# linux bash, command 'gnome-terminal", escape quote

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

From linux, I open terminal via the command "gnome-terminal" and run some command like that :

```
test="foo";gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash "echo $test"
```

Now, I would like run an echo containing quote like that :

```
test="foo\'s";gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash "echo $test'"
```

But that does not work..the anti-slash seems haven't any effect. I tried anothers syntax :

```
test="foo\\'s";gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash "echo $test"
test="foo\\\'s";gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash "echo $test"
...
```

How can I escape the quote from a simple echo executed in a gnome-terminal command ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
test="foo\'s"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo \"$test\"; sleep 10"
```